# Kendo Nested Grid name cannot be blank

Tags: c#, kendo-grid, .net-5

I'm at a loss.
I am trying to build a nested grid using Kendo ui tools.
I have a very similar grid that works perfectly, but there is something missing in mine, as  I keep getting a "Name cannot be blank" error.

Here is my index.cshtml

```
@{
    int w1 = 150;
    int w2 = 120;
}

<style>
    .green {
        background-color: greenyellow !important;
    }
</style>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert" id="alert-box-error" style="display:none">
                Errore !
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            @(
                Html.Kendo()
                    .Grid<ModelsExceptionsVM>()
                    .Name("Grid")
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 800px" })
                    .Columns(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.Bound(m => m.ExceptionId).Visible(false);
                        columns.Bound(m => m.ExceptionCode).Title("Codice").Visible(false);
                        columns.Bound(m => m.ReportCode).Title("Report").Filterable(ftb => ftb.Multi(true).Search(true)).Width(w2);//.EditorTemplateName("ReportsDropdown");
                        columns.Bound(m => m.Description).Title("Descrizione").Filterable(ftb => ftb.Multi(true).Search(true)).Width(w1);//.EditorTemplateName("SupplierDropdown");
                        columns.Command(c => c.Destroy()).Width(60);
                })
                .ToolBar(toolbar =>
                {
                    toolbar.Save();
                    @*toolbar.Excel();*@
                    toolbar.Create();
                    toolbar.Search();

                })
                .Editable(editable => editable
                    .Mode(GridEditMode.InCell)
                    .DisplayDeleteConfirmation(true)
                    )
                .Pageable(pageable => pageable
                    .Refresh(true)
                    .PageSizes(true)
                    .ButtonCount(5)
                )
                .Navigatable()
                .Sortable()
                .Filterable()
                .Scrollable()
                .ClientDetailTemplateId("template")
                .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
                .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
                .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                    .Ajax()
                    .PageSize(20)
                    .Batch(true)
                    .ServerOperation(false)
                   .Model(model =>
                    {
                        model.Id(x => x.ExceptionId);
                    })
                    .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Models"))
                    .Update(update => update.Action("Update", "Models"))
                    .Create(create => create.Action("Create", "Models"))
                    .Destroy(delete => delete.Action("Delete", "Models"))
                )
                )
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<script id="template" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<ModelException>()
                        .Name("grid_#=ExceptionId#")
                    .Columns(columns =>
                        {
                            columns.Bound(m => m.ExceptionReportsModelId).Title("Id").Visible(false);
                            columns.Bound(o => o.Model).Title("Modello").Width(100);
                            columns.Bound(o => o.ReportValue).Title("Valore").Width(100);
                            columns.Command(c => c.Destroy()).Width(60);
                    })
                    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                             .Ajax()
                        .Batch(true)
                        .ServerOperation(false)
                                 .Read(read => read.Action("Hierarchy_ModelRead", "Models", new { ExceptionId = "#=ExceptionId#" }))
                                     .Update(update => update.Action("Hierarchy_ModelUpdate", "Models", new { ExceptionId = "#=ExceptionId#" }))
                                     .Create(create => create.Action("Hierarchy_ModelCreate", "Models", new { ExceptionId = "#=ExceptionId#" }))
                                     .Destroy(delete => delete.Action("Hierarchy_ModelDelete", "Models", new { ExceptionId = "#=ExceptionId#" }))
@*                                 .Model(model =>
                            {
                                model.Id(x => x.ExceptionReportsModelId);
                            })*@
                        )
                        .Editable(editable => editable
                                    .Mode(GridEditMode.InCell)
                                    .DisplayDeleteConfirmation(true)
                            )
                        .ToolBar(toolbar =>
                        {
                            toolbar.Save();
                            toolbar.Create();

                        })
                    .ToClientTemplate()
            )
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
        function onError() {
            $("#alert-box-error")
                .fadeIn('slow')
                .delay(3000)
                .fadeOut('slow');
        }
    </script>
```

it seems that the issue is with the template component (the actual nested grid), because if I remove it, the main grid works.

The models:

```
 public class ModelsExceptionsVM
    {
        public Guid ExceptionId { get; set; }
        public int ExceptionCode { get;  set; }
        public string ReportCode { get;  set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

    public class  ModelException
    {
        public Guid ExceptionReportsModelId { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string ReportValue { get; set; }
    }
```

the controller:

```
  [Area("Exceptions")]
    public class ModelsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly DepartmentsContext _db;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public ModelsController(DepartmentsContext db, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _db = db;
            _configuration = configuration;
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, [Bind(Prefix = "models")] IEnumerable<ModelsExceptionsVM> vMs)
        {
            if (vMs != null)
            {
                foreach (var ex in vMs)
                {
                    var create = new Persistence.Models.ExceptionsReports();
                    create.ReportCode = ex.ReportCode;
                    create.Description = ex.Description;
                    _db.ExceptionsReports.Add(create);
                }
                await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }

            return Json(vMs.ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }

        public async Task<ActionResult> Hierarchy_ModelCreate(Guid ExceptionId, [DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, [Bind(Prefix = "models")] IEnumerable<ModelException> vMs)
        {
            if (vMs != null)
            {
                foreach (var ex in vMs)
                {
                    var create = new Persistence.Models.ExceptionReportsModels();
                    create.ValueForReport = ex.ReportValue;
                    create.Model = ex.Model;
                    _db.ExceptionReportsModels.Add(create);
                }
                await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }

            return Json(vMs.ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }

        public async Task<ActionResult> Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            var result = await _db.ExceptionsReports
            .OrderBy(x => x.ExceptionCode)
            .Select(x=>new ModelsExceptionsVM
            {
                Description = x.Description,
                ExceptionCode = x.ExceptionCode,
                ExceptionId = x.ExceptionId,
                ReportCode = x.ReportCode,
            })   
            .ToListAsync();

            return Json(result.ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }
        public async Task<ActionResult> Hierarchy_ModelRead(Guid ExceptionId, [DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            var data = await _db.ExceptionReportsModels
                .Where(x => x.ExceptionId == ExceptionId)
                .Select(z=> new ModelException
                {
                    ExceptionReportsModelId =z.ExceptionsReportsModelId,
                    Model = z.Model,
                    ReportValue = z.ValueForReport
                })
                .ToListAsync();

            return Json(data.ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }

        public async Task<ActionResult> Update([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, [Bind(Prefix = "models")] IEnumerable<ModelsExceptionsVM> vMs)
        {
            if (vMs != null)
            {
                foreach (var ex in vMs)
                {
                    var update = await _db.ExceptionsReports.FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => ex.ExceptionCode == t.ExceptionCode);
                    update.ReportCode = ex.ReportCode;
                    update.Description = ex.Description;
                }
                await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }

            return Json(vMs.ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }

        public async Task<ActionResult> Hierarchy_ModelUpdate(Guid ExceptionId, [DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, [Bind(Prefix = "models")] IEnumerable<ModelException> vMs)
        {
            if (vMs != null)
            {
                foreach (var ex in vMs)
                {
                    var update = await _db.ExceptionReportsModels.FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => ex.ExceptionReportsModelId == t.ExceptionsReportsModelId);
                    update.Model = ex.Model;
                    update.ValueForReport = ex.ReportValue;
                }
                await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }

            return Json(vMs.ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }
        public async Task<ActionResult> Delete([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, [Bind(Prefix = "models")] IEnumerable<ModelsExceptionsVM> vMs)
        {
            if (vMs != null)
            {
                foreach (ModelsExceptionsVM vM in vMs)
                {

                    var dvME = await _db.ExceptionsReports.FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.ExceptionCode == vM.ExceptionCode);
                    if (dvME != null)
                    {
                        _db.ExceptionsReports.Remove(dvME);
                    }
                }
                await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            return Json(vMs.ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }
        public async Task<ActionResult> Hierarchy_ModelDelete(Guid ExceptionId, [DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, [Bind(Prefix = "models")] IEnumerable<ModelException> vMs)
        {
            if (vMs != null)
            {
                foreach (ModelException vM in vMs)
                {

                    var dvME = await _db.ExceptionReportsModels.FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.ExceptionsReportsModelId == vM.ExceptionReportsModelId);
                    if (dvME != null)
                    {
                        _db.ExceptionReportsModels.Remove(dvME);
                    }
                }
                await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            return Json(vMs.ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }
    }
```

I have tried commenting and uncommenting pretty much everything to no avail. Renaming the template, changing the model... What could I be missing?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I have commented all the editable parts (so the .Editable() function, the Destroy() function in the columns, and the save/create functions in the toolbar) of the nested grid and now works fine. But I do need the editing part, so what gives?

Comment: I'm not 100% certain, butI think it might be caused by the template not liking ExceptionId being a Guid.   Try converting to a string first i.e. add a read only property to ModelsExceptionsVM, that returns ExceptionId.ToString(), and use that in the template instead.

Comment: @Stewart I've attempted that, but it changed nothing.